# Arangoimp states that everything ran correctly, but data does not appear in database

Tags: arangodb

I run arangoimp on my json formatted data like this, and the output of arangoimp states that everything ran correctly.

```
arangoimp --file data.json --collection newCollection --create-collection true --server.password "" --progress false
```

with output

```
Starting JSON import...
created:          28538
warnings/errors:  0
updated/replaced: 0
ignored:          0
```

When I view the database in the web client, there is no data there. I am able to upload data to the database with pyArango, however this is much slower and I would prefer not to. Any ideas as to why arangoimp is not working correctly?
Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the data was being inserted into `_system` database. Problem is easily fixed by adding flag `--server.database myDB` to my command.